# Creating a drop down list only if United States is selected

Tags: html

I want to create a drop down list of states if the country selected is the United States, and if not, just have a fill in text space. How can I do this in HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must implement javaScript in your html in order to do so. Easiest way is to Hide /Unhide the Textbox and Drop-down depending on the selected item on first selected box.

HTML:

```
<!--Your Source Drop down-->
<select name="select1" id="select1">
    <option value="Country1">Country 1</option>
    <option value="US">United States</option>
</select>


<select name="select2" id="select2">
<!--List of States Here-->
</select>

<!--The Textbox (hidden)-->
<input type="text" id="case" name="myText" style="display:none">
```

On JavaScript:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var select1 = document.getElementById("select1");
    var select2 = document.getElementById("select2");
    var text1 = document.getElementById("case");

    select1.onchange = function() {

        //Show States, Hide Textbox (US Selected)
        if (select1.selectedIndex == 1) {
            select2.style.display='block';
            text1.style.display='none';
        }
        else //Hide States, Show Textbox (Other Country is Selected)
        {
            select2.style.display='none';
            text1.style.display='block';
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: thanks a lot! one question--any idea how I can make the state box appear next to the country drop down? the way it is now, it appears on the next line

Comment: @user66528 You can use _table_ or other HTML tags to align it to way you like it. If this answered your question, don't forget to select the best answer by clicking the check box (^v^).